# In my code the camera can rotate on click but it instantaneously sets the rotation to 90 degree how can i make it to be a smooth transition

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

I want to create an app where I can rotate the camera to view a specific entity but my camera rotates instantaneously how can I make it a smooth transition

I tried attaching animation component to camera but due to look-controls component the rotation is overridden

([click here](https://glitch.com/~spangled-baritone)) to see the code

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question itself. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Look into "tweening." There are several JavaScript libraries that can perform the calculations for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because look-controls overrides rotation component on the camera, you can't set or animate rotation directly.

One solution would be to disable look controls (or possibly remove it), and then perform the animation on rotation. Then when it finishes, enable (or add back in) the look-controls component.

Another solution is to use THREEjs camera control to set and animate the camera.
Animation component only works on other component properties. So you need to make a custom component, and animate a schema property of that component. Then inside the component, in update(), you set the threejs rotation of the camera from the schema property.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('camcontrol',{
        schema: {
            rot: { type: 'vec3'} ,
            animactive: { type: 'boolean', default: false } },
        init: function(){
            let self = this;
            this.el.addEventListener('loaded', function(){
                self.cam3d = self.el.object3D.children[0];
                self.cam3d.name = "camera"
                console.log('cam3d', self.cam3d);
                // Clone the camera, used for looking at new targets
                self.dummyCam3d = self.cam3d.clone();
                self.el.object3D.add(self.dummyCam3d);
                // Create a new group. make it a child of the dummyCam
                self.dummyUp = new THREE.Object3D();
                self.dummyCam3d.add(self.dummyUp);
                self.dummyUp.translateY(1.0);
                console.log('dummyCam3d', self.dummyCam3d);
                self.loaded = true;
            });
            this.el.addEventListener('animationcomplete__look', function(){
                self.data.animactive = false;
                console.log('anim complete. rotation: ', self.cam3d.rotation);
            });
        },
        update: function(){
            if (this.data.animactive){
                let rot = this.data.rot;
                // console.log('update: rot ', rot);
                let euler = new THREE.Euler( rot.x, rot.y, rot.z, 'ZXY');
                this.cam3d.setRotationFromEuler(euler);
            }

        },
        lookAnimation: function(pos){
            console.log('camcontrol.lookAnimation', pos);
            let camRot = this.cam3d.rotation;
            let camWP = new THREE.Vector3();            
            this.cam3d.getWorldPosition(camWP);

            this.dummyCam3d.position = camWP;
            // this.dummyCam3d.up = new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0);
            this.dummyCam3d.lookAt(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z);

            let dumCamRot = this.dummyCam3d.rotation;

            console.log("dumCamRot", dumCamRot );
            this.data.animactive = true;    
            this.el.setAttribute('animation__look', { from: {x: camRot.x, y: camRot.y, z: camRot.z}, to:{x: dumCamRot.x, y:  dumCamRot.y, z: 0} });
            this.el.emit('camlook');
        }
    });

<a-scene>
        <a-entity id="button1" geometry="primitive: box" position="1 0 -5" class="clickable" material="color: tomato" button3d></a-entity>
        <a-entity  id="button2" geometry="primitive: octahedron; radius: 0.2" position="-4 0 -3" class="clickable" material="color: #4466BB" button3d></a-entity> 
        <a-entity  id="button3" geometry="primitive: sphere; radius: 0.2" position="2 0 -2" class="clickable" material="color: green" button3d></a-entity> 
        <a-entity  id="button4" geometry="primitive: cone; radius: 0.2" position="-3 0 -8" class="clickable" material="color: purple" button3d></a-entity>
        <a-entity  id="button5" geometry="primitive: icosahedron; radius: 0.2" position="0 0 0" class="clickable" material="color: blue" button3d></a-entity> 

        <a-sky color="#bbddff"></a-sky>

        <a-entity id="camrig" position="0 0 0" ></a-entity>
            <a-entity id="camera" position="0 0 0" fov="100" camera look-controls camcontrol
            animation__look="property: camcontrol.rot; startEvents: camlook; dur:500"></a-entity>
        </a-entity>

        <a-entity id="mouseCursor" cursor="rayOrigin: mouse" raycaster="objects: .clickable"></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
```

glitch [here](https://glitch.com/~lookcontrols-lookatanim)

Comment: This solution works, but it has problems with rotation. It's probably due to using euler angles and the dreaded gimbal lock. Redoing this with quaternions might solve it, but that is a bit involved. This at least illustrates the idea of how to animate a THREEjs property of the camera.